# Count repeating elements in a CSV column

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm currently trying to get used to Python and am trying to read a column and count the repeating elements from the strings.

What I have so far:

```
i = 0
y = [i]
fav_Split = row[9].split('|')
#print fav_Split

for x in fav_Split:
    #print x
    y[i] = x
    i = i+1
```

`print fav_Split` gives me:

```
['XA', 'MA']
['BA', 'MA', 'RA']
['EB', 'CB']
['JA', 'RB', 'RA']
['ED', 'EA', 'RB', 'KA', 'RA']
['SB']
['MA', 'ED', 'SB']
['EC']
['FA']
['RA', 'MA']
['RB']
['CB']
['AC']
['CB', 'MA', 'RA']
['AC']
['KA']
['SA', 'CB']
['BA', 'ED', 'MA']
['KA', 'ED', 'SA']
['AB']
['CA']
['AB']
['SB', 'MA']
['XA', 'BA', 'CA']
['SA', 'AB']
['SA', 'XA', 'CA']
['KA']
['MA', 'XA']
['MA']
['RA', 'EC', 'JA']
['RA']
['CC', 'RA']
['CC']
['CC', 'RA']
['SA', 'RA']
['RA', 'AC']
['XA', 'JA', 'RA']
['CB', 'KA', 'RA']
['ZZ']
['CB', 'SA', 'RA']
['MA']
['LA', 'RB', 'RA']
['XA', 'RA']
['GA', 'RA', 'LA']
```

`print x` gives me:

```
XA
MA
BA
MA
RA
EB
CB
JA
RB
RA
ED
EA
RB
KA
RA
SB
MA
ED
SB
EC
FA
RA
MA
RB
CB
AC
CB
MA
RA
AC
KA
SA
CB
BA
ED
MA
KA
ED
SA
AB
CA
AB
SB
MA
XA
BA
CA
SA
AB
SA
XA
CA
KA
MA
XA
MA
RA
EC
JA
RA
CC
RA
CC
CC
RA
SA
RA
RA
AC
XA
JA
RA
CB
KA
RA
ZZ
CB
SA
RA
MA
LA
RB
RA
XA
RA
GA
RA
LA
```

Which is what I want. I'm trying to read those separate vars into an array and simply count them afterwards. But I am getting an error when trying to read into the y array

```
y[i] = x
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Can anyone help me with this? My next steps are counting the repeating elements and displaying the top X (which can be changed based on user input).

UPDATE 2:
Debugging pic:
I don't understand here: y is...not...seeing x as its own element?
[image]

UPDATE 3:
for y += x
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has nothing to do with CSV (or Excel).  Counting strings should have nothing to do with where those strings came from.

Comment: The data is from a CVS file originally, the script as a whole is reading in from CSV and writing out to a new CSV, then calling a VBA macro to further modify the CSV data, then renaming the CSV file with a timestamp...I should specify more I guess :P     - I will remove the tags if it is not necessary

Comment: 1.  (Re-)read "[ask]" --- images are _not_ a substitute for code.  Even if the image link survives, it can't be turned into a [mcve].  Also, images can't tell us what you think is wrong... they just show Python doing what Python does when you tell it to do that (which is fine in my book).

Comment: 2.  Your "update 3" is a completely unrelated question, so don't ask it here --- ask it as a new question.  Better yet, ask _yourself_ what you expected `y += x` to do.  Then experiment with it a bit in a new Python interpreter and read the Python docs.  Learn [what it actually does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).  This is the sort of thing you can work out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me give you an improvement to your original code:

```
y = []
fav_Split = row[9].split('|') 
#print fav_Split

for x in fav_Split:
    y += x
```

Or, even shorter:

```
fav_split = row[9].split('|')
y = [item for sublist in fav_Split for item in sublist]
```

Okay, now we have the list of two-letter-codes you wanted. The next step is using the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which seems to be exactly what you need. You pass a list to it, and it computes the occurences of each element and orders it descending by its occurences.

```
import collections.Counter
c = collections.Counter(y)
```

To get the `n` most common elements from your list, you can simply use [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

```
c.most_common(n)
```

which will

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will get on this now, Oh

Comment: Oh, I remember I tried this earlier! 
I did not know about collect function though. My result for printing c is: 
Counter({'XA': 1, 'MA': 1})
Counter({'MA': 1, 'BA': 1, 'RA': 1})
Counter({'CB': 1, 'EB': 1})
Counter({'JA': 1, 'RB': 1, 'RA': 1})
Counter({'ED': 1, 'KA': 1, 'EA': 1, 'RA': 1, 'RB': 1})
Counter({'SB': 1})
Counter({'ED': 1, 'MA': 1, 'SB': 1})
Counter({'EC': 1})
....etc
In this case, it seems to be adding each separate array as a separate element to this list

Comment: @BrianGeoghegan That shouldn't be the case. Once you've got an array like the `x`from your question, you can just pass it to `collections.Counter` and use it. I don't see how there are separate arrays. Your result looks more like the result of a `map` on a list of stuff.

Comment: Not sure if i'm misinterpreting, however, I suspected expactly what you are describing, however, the result of y.append(x) is very close to the result of fav_Split. As far as I was aware, I thought, y.append(x) would give me

{XA,MA,BA,MA,RA,EB,CB,JA,RB ....etc}

Comment: @BrianGeoghegan You should track down where the code and the results start to differ. Reading your question, you seem to have a way to get to your `x` list. Start from there and use `collections.Counter`, just edit the first part if everything else works.

Comment: I will add a pic in the first post

Comment: @BrianGeoghegan Sorry, I've had an error in my first "solution". It's fixed now. Please try again.

Comment: No problem Carsten thanks for you help, i'm getting an equally strange error now I will post it above

Comment: @BrianGeoghegan Please use a new question for that if its outside the exact scope of this one.

Comment: Its not a new question, its with the new solution, this is confusing me quite alot...i'm used to Java and C arrays,..Javascript... but this one is boggling my mind